# c++ multimap, return submap where key is between MIN and MAX

Tags: c++, multimap

Using c++, i have a multimap. 
From this multimap i want to get a submap where the keys are withing a MIN and MAX value.

Somthing like :

```
mmap->insert(1,classInstance); 
mmap->insert(2,classInstance);
mmap->insert(3,classInstance);
mmap->insert(4,classInstance);
mmap->insert(2,classInstance2);
mmap->insert(5,classInstance);
mmap->insert(6,classInstance);

submap = mmap->submap(2,5);

result is a submap with 
2,classInstance
3,classInstance
4,classInstance
2,classInstance2
5,classInstance
as values
```

How would i achieved this ?
Thanks !

Comment: 1. Have you tried anything? `lower_bound`, `upper_bound` etc.? 2. Why is you map accessed through a pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use class member functions `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct classInstance {};

int main() 
{
    std::multimap<int, classInstance> mmap;

    mmap.insert( { 1, classInstance() } ); 
    mmap.insert( { 2, classInstance() } );
    mmap.insert( { 3, classInstance() } );
    mmap.insert( { 4, classInstance() } );
    mmap.insert( { 2, classInstance() } );
    mmap.insert( { 5, classInstance() } );
    mmap.insert( { 6, classInstance() } );

    auto first = mmap.lower_bound( 2 );
    auto last  = mmap.upper_bound( 5 );

    while ( first != last ) std::cout << first++->first << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
2
2
3
4
5
```

The while loop can be substituted for the for loop like

```
    for ( ; first != last; ++first ) std::cout << first->first << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you very much !  My reputation is to low to accept the answer :(